Currently arguing with my teacher about this electromagnetism question, any helpers?
Sorry if my Q is simple, I'm still in high school.
I'm currently arguing with my physics teacher regarding a Q, shown below.

The answers state this.

However, I am attempting to argue that the gradient is not necessarily negative, and is purely dependent on the strength of the field, if the B field is weak, then the gradient is not necessary negative. However, my teacher keeps on referring to a "impulsive force" which is guaranteed to exceed the force of gravity and decelerate the object. He also keeps on referring to the experiment where a magnet falls through a copper pipe and keeps stating that the velocity of the object decreases in the tube, as evidence for this "impulsive force". I am attempting to argue that the force on the object is mg-BIL, and thus if B field is not strong enough, the net force on the object is still down. How might I disprove his argument?

I think this whole thing is wrong. You are wrong, the answer key is ridiculously wrong, and so is your teacher. The slowdown of the magnet through copper pipe, or copper ring through magnetic field, is very dramatic and ought to be at a small terminal velocity rather than accelerating. You should just work out the specific terminal velocity as a function of magnetic field, and that should suffice for whatever argument you actually want to draw.

@naturallyInconsistent why would the ring feel the magnetic field when the flux is not changing?

It is a poor answer and the analysis of the arrangement can be made simpler by assuming that a square, rather than a ring, of side $\ell$, mass $m$ and resistance $R$ is falling.
When in a uniform (including zero) magnetic field the acceleration of the square will be $g$ downwards, the acceleration of free fall, and so there will be the three regions where the gradient of the velocity time graph is constant and positive.
Whilst in the region where the magnetic flux through the square changes there is an induced emf $B\ell v$ where $B$ is the magnetic field strength a $v$ is the velocity of the ring, and this results in a force of $\frac{B^2\ell^2 v}{R}$ on the ring.
The velocity in this region is described by an exponential function with an asymptote at a terminal velocity of $v_{\rm T} = \frac{mgR}{B^2\ell^2}$.
There are three possible outcomes of the transition from no change of magnetic flux through the square to the magnetic flux changing.
One is the square arriving at a transition at the terminal velocity $v_{\rm T}$ which will result in the velocity-time graph being horizontal whilst the magnetic flux is changing.
At velocities of arrival less than $v_{\rm T}$, the velocity-time graph will have a positive gradient of decreasing magnitude from $g$, ie the velocity of the square will still be increasing but at slower rate.
At velocities of arrival greater than $v_{\rm T}$, the velocity-time graph will have a negative gradient of decreasing magnitude, ie the velocity of the ring will be decreasing but at a slow and slower rate.
What actually happens at each of the transition points depends on the values of the various parameter and that being so means that it is also a poor question.

$B\ell v$ has the dimension of force per charge; $\frac{B^2\ell^2v}{R}$ has the dimension of force per mass.

@J.G. $\bf[B\ell v] = (M^1T^{-2}I^{-1})\cdot (L^1) \cdot (L^1T^{-1}) = M^1L^2T^{-3}I^{-1} =[voltage]\Rightarrow [B^2\ell^2v/R]=(M^1T^{-2}I^{-1})^2\cdot (L^1)^2\cdot (L^1T^{-1}) /(M^1L^2T^{-3}I^{-2})  =M^1L^1T^{-2} =[force] \Rightarrow [mgR/(B^2\ell^2)]=(M^1)\cdot(L^1T^{-2})\cdot(M^1L^2T^{-3}I^{-2})/\left((M^1T^{-2}I^{-1})^2\cdot(L^1)^2\right) =L^1T^{-1}=[velocity]$

I agree with that part.
